# How to calculate IEEE 802.11 CRC-32 FCS?

Tags: wifi, checksum, crc

This is from IEEE Std 802.11-2012 Clause 8.2.4.8 FCS field:

[image]

I cannot understand the last two paragraphs:

1. What's the meaning by "the initial remainder of the division is preset to all ones", and why we need to do that?
2. What's the meaning by "... the serial incoming bits of the calculation fields and FCS..." ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Initializing the CRC to all ones avoids the problem of a string of zeros of any length giving a zero CRC.
2. Read [Ross Williams CRC tutorial](http://zlib.net/crc_v3.txt).

Comment: the link to the tutorial is broken

Comment: @GiladBeeri Good thing I copied that to my web site a while back in case this happened. I have updated the link in the answer.