# The polynomial of WEP CRC32

Tags: crc, polynomial-math, crc32, wep

This is for my school project. I'm trying to understand the CRC32 implemented in WEP. I've only got one question, which I haven't been able to answer. What polynomial does the WEP algorithm use?

Tristan

Comment: It's probably the IEEE CRC-32, which uses a Hamming code. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code about how to develop the polynomial.

Comment: Um, no -- CRC's and Hamming codes are two entirely different things.

Comment: See this [question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16103328/1180620) for the CRC-32 used in 802.11.